# Pros and Cons of University vs Research only Institute

Tags: research-process, university, job, government-institutes

I love doing research, only research with no teaching duties.

What are the pros and cons of having a job in a university and in a research only institute?

If you were me, which one would you choose?

Are there more money in universities? Do universities do more cutting edge research if compared to research only institutes?

My countries of interest are the north European ones (within the EU).

Thanks